# Why is there no save confirmation when closing a file?

Tags: interface

[image]
I was working in the default file which was not saved. And suddenly I remember I want to open a different file and from the file menu I selected the file. The old file open but the problem the file which was working (default file) was not saved. Blender did not prompt that you want to save the file. I lost the model from the default file and the old file open. Is there any function or why there is no pop-up for blender to save.

Comment: I am pretty sure there is no way to activate such dialog when opening new file while the current one is changed... and I miss that feature too. But you can try to "recover last session" on the startup popup.

Comment: There used to be a time blender didn't even presented us with a dialog when closing blender.
Hell... it didn't even had CTRL+Z function back in the days.
My guess is this will eventually be integrated. (keeping fingers crossed).
You might take the advise of Jan Kadeřábek.  check out your autobackup settings under 'user preferences'.

Comment: It did not work recover last session giving an error message : cannot read file C:/...............

Comment: Use Recover Auto Save...

Answer (score 1):

Currently Blender does not have a 'Do You want To Save?' warning before opening a new or previous file. There is a dialog box that pops up of course, but it definitely could be a lot clearer as to what will happen when you confirm.

Blender does have several ways to recover lost files though.

First is the 'Recover Last Session' option in the file menu which you already know about based on your question. From my experience this usually doesn't do a great job of recovering in a case like yours as it goes back too far.

Blender also auto saves files. In the user preferences in the file tab you can set it to auto save more frequently (down to every 1 minute). Autosaves can be recovered from the file menu. Do note that Sculpt and Edit Mode changes won't be saved by Auto Save though (and I'm not exactly sure why that wasn't implemented, my guess would be a full save takes too long).

Finally blender created backup versions of your files. These are the .blend1 and .blend2 files that get automatically created after a while. You can open these versions using the default open menu and adjusting the filter settings at the top to display .blend1 and .blend2 files.